# Onclick javascript to make browser go back to previous page?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, onclick, dom-events

Is there a function I can attach as a click event of a button to make the browser go back to previous page?

```
<input name="action" type="submit" value="Cancel"/>
```

Comment: window.history.back()

Answer (score 545, accepted):

Add this in your input element

```
<input
    action="action"
    onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;"
    type="submit"
    value="Cancel"
/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in all browsers for me, I had to do the following `<input action="action" type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;" />`
This answer is quite old, so it could have been an issue introduced into more modern versions of browsers. :)

Comment: Does this show the previous page from cache or reloads the previous page from the server?

Comment: What's the `action="action"` part for? And is it valid html??

Comment: @Adrien - its javascript, so it is running in the browser. The browser should reuse cached page (assuming browser settings and page http header settings permit doing so).

Comment: Note that inline JS should not be used in production because:
1. JS code should be in dedicated and minified `.js` files

2. inline JS should be disabled through a Content Security Policy to mitigate XSS injections

Comment: Any idea why this not always working from the first time? It doesn't seem that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034274/duplicate-history-enteries-using-history-pushstate-in-chrome-safari) was answered so far.

Comment: This one still works in Chrome, Brave browser. 2024

Answer (score 162):

```
history.back()
```

or

```
history.go(-1)
```

Put this to the button `onclick` handle. It should look like this:

```
<input name="action" onclick="history.back()" type="submit" value="Cancel"/>
```

Comment: Put this to the button onClick handle

Comment: You could be more clear like giving the answer in the code

Comment: What's the browser support on that?

Comment: @Costa [pretty good](https://caniuse.com/?search=history), unless you're developing to Opera Mini.

Answer (score 116):

For Going to previous page

**First Method**

```
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Go Back</a>
```

**Second Method**

```
<a href="##" onClick="history.go(-1); return false;">Go back</a>
```

if we want to more than one step back then increase

```
For going 2 steps back history.go(-2)
For going 3 steps back history.go(-3)
For going 4 steps back history.go(-4)
and so on.......
```

Comment: @JeromeJ it is a link that does nothing if JavaScript isn't enabled/working (for whatever reason) on the page. If JavaScript is working, it takes the browser back one page.

Answer (score 17):

Works for me everytime

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">
    <button type="button">
        Back
    </button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 16):

```
<input name="action" type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="window.history.back();"/>
```

Answer (score 16):

Simple. One line.

```
<button onclick="javascript:window.history.back();">Go Back</button>
```

Like Wim's and Malik's answer, but just in one line.

Comment: Works fine, but oftentimes if user decides to change language on specific page with the button like this, the back button to previous page will turn the language back, instead of page...

Answer (score 14):

Shortest Yet!

```
<button onclick="history.go(-1);">Go back</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qXrbx/

I prefer the `.go(-number)` method as then, for 1 or many 'backs' there's only 1 method to use/remember/update/search for, etc.

Also, using a  tag for a back button seems more appropriate than tags with names and types...

Answer (score 14):

> **window.history.back();**

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 12):

You just need to call the following:

```
history.go(-1);
```

Answer (score 7):

Access `window.history` and then call `back()`

```
window.history.back()
```

Comment: some of the others didn't take me to the previous page if I had reloaded, but this one does

Answer (score 6):

This is the only thing that works on all current browsers:

```
<script>
function goBack() {
    history.go(-1);
}
</script>
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

the only one that worked for me:

```js
function goBackAndRefresh() {
  window.history.go(-1);
  setTimeout(() => {
    location.reload();
  }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the following :

`history.back()` or `window.history.back()`

You also go back to N number of pages with this one
`history.go(-1)`

Comment: Isn't `history.back()` the same as `history.go(-1)` & `window.history.back()` ? Please do add a bit more of context

Comment: The window.history object can be written without the window prefix, that's why history.back(), history.go(-1) & window.history.back() will do the same. but if we want to go back to N number of pages then history.go(-n) can use. example: history.go(-1) will go 1 page back from current, history.go(-2) will go 2 pages back from the current. Thanks Raphaël Balet.

Answer (score -1):

100% work

```html
<a onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;" style="cursor: pointer;">Go Back</a>
```