# Spring MVC Application (Back button)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, back-button

On my MVC spring application I send a form to a page using GET method to perform a search. The results of the search is a list and, for every entry is possible to navigate to a details page. It works fine.
Now, I want to have a back button on the detail page which should take back to the searched list.

I can call the same controller method to reevaluate but it performs Data Base calls, which I don't want to do.
What is the best solution?

Answer (score 9):

You want it to perform database calls don't you ? What if the data has been changed by a differet user?

[If not  you can use javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067510/onclick-javascript-to-make-browser-go-back-to-previous-page)  :

```
<input action="action" type="button" onclick="history.go(-1);" />
```