# implement back button in javascript similar to browser

Tags: javascript, html

I want to Implement Back button Similar to how the browser . I don't have any idea on how to Do this . Please suggest me a way whether i can do it in java script .

Comment: Ok,Show me what you have tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Onclick javascript to make browser go back to previous page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067510/onclick-javascript-to-make-browser-go-back-to-previous-page)

Comment: it is simple problem, you should try first at your end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
   <input onclick='javascript:window.history.back()' value='Back' type='button' />

   <input onclick='javascript:window.history.forward()' value='Next' type='button'  />
```

this is simple javascript.

Note this will not work in following cases:

1. History is cleared
2. Open in new browser
3. Ajax based websites, as no history is maintained for ajax driven applications.

Comment: I want a buttton like thing a the bottom of my page . So that whenever a user clicks back . It just goes to the previous page or Next button for forward page

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<button onclick="window.history.back()">Go Back</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.history.go(-1);">Back</button>
```