# How to navigate from one page to another using back button Iin webpage

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i have five buttons in my project. i want to use one back button. With the help of the back button i should back to the recent page from where i came yet.

```
Code
$("#back").click(function(e) 
e.preventDefault();
$("iframe").attr('src',"loginTumbnail.html");
 });
```

[image: These are Buttons]

Comment: The answer is already available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067510/onclick-javascript-to-make-browser-go-back-to-previous-page)

Comment: NO dear you did not understand what i want. i mean when i click on home button and then contact button... with the help of back button i want to go to the recent page from where i came soon.