# Google Login form clears LocalStorage values

Tags: javascript, local-storage, google-signin

I am working with Login with Google, I observed that Google Login form clears a LocalStorage, SessionStorage and session values. Is there any way I can keep this values? or any other ways to keep some values to use after login.
I tried for Stackoverflow site too, gave me same result.
[I set some values and tried to get. I got the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2UhV.png)

But when I clicked on Login with Google and tried, I get nothing.
[On Login with google form of same site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNjGY.png)

Comment: Seems unlikely-- if I were to _guess_ I'd say it is done for security purposes.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: after login I want to jump to previous page url which I was storing on LocalStorage. Facebook login allows me to store value in LocalStorage.

Comment: so the *Security is compromised* messages don't worry you at all/

Comment: Is there any other way I can keep some values after login ? I tried PHP Sessions too but seems not working too.

Comment: @anied any clue, what I can do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Google login API-- If it is possible and Facebook is doing it then I'd recommend starting at the documentation.  Perhaps they are leveraging [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067510/onclick-javascript-to-make-browser-go-back-to-previous-page) sort of programmatic Javascript history solution.  Or perhaps there is a callback or value you can pass.  Or you could try debugging Facebook's process.  But keep security in mind.

Comment: @anied Thank you, I'll try this.