# Google form clears PHP Session values

Tags: php, session, google-oauth, google-signin

I am using google login form to login to my website, I am passing some values by $_SESSOIN. I am getting that values till login of my website, but when it comes to Google Sign in form, after that it clears $_SESSION values. 
What can be the reason? Is there any other way I can get the value after login?

- What do I want to achieve?

I want to redirect to user to the previous page after login with google. So I was storing page URL in session variable like $_SESSION["pageUrl"].

Is there any other way to handle this case if I am doing this wrong?

Comment: is this related to a previous question you asked? http://stackoverflow.com/q/43222266/1415724 - seems like it.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to get the value by LocalStorage but failed so I tried with Session but not get success too.

Comment: you'd need to either update your previous question or delete it; this as per Stack's rules constitutes as a repost and it may get closed as an exact duplicate.

Comment: But this is other query, previous was about client side script (JavaScript) using LocalStorage and this one is for PHP SESSION.