# Call to a member function where() on float in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Its not duplicate question. Sorry for such type of starting.

```
$sum = DB::table('tasklists')->sum('list_weight')->where('task_id','10');
```

it show me Call to a member function where() on float. I am trying to find out the reason ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sum` after the `where` as you need to condition first and take output later.

What happens is when you call a function on `DB` which generates a output or query result, The facade runs the query and gets you the output.

So, in your case when you call `sum` the query prepared before `sum` is get executed and `sum` returns the sum of results i.e. `float`.

Now, you are trying to access `where` method on a float(which is output of the `sum`) not on the query itself.

That is why you are getting the error.

Comment: I am facing another problem on URL::previous() . When I use it in multiple pages it makes loop . My expectation is to make back button. can u tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Yes it would definately behave like this. If you just want to replicate the browsers back behaviour just use javascript's `window.history.back()`. [Onclick javascript to make browser go back to previous page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067510/onclick-javascript-to-make-browser-go-back-to-previous-page)

Comment: Thanks again. but i want to refresh page when I go back