# go back previouse page javascript

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

iam working on a tampermonkey script (javascript), and i need a help about go back to the previouse page, i already tryed some codes but did not worked, the code used can go back to the previouse page but after loading the back again to the first page and a loop of back and foward is started please help i want only back to previouse page and stop
the codes used before

```
history.back()
```

and

```
window.history.go(-1)
```

and

```
if (history.length) {
    //There is history to go back to
    history.go(-1);
}
```

Comment: java is to javascript as ham is to hamster (i.e. completely and utterly unrelated). I fixed your tags for you.

Comment: Does this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067510/onclick-javascript-to-make-browser-go-back-to-previous-page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Onclick javascript to make browser go back to previous page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067510/onclick-javascript-to-make-browser-go-back-to-previous-page)

Answer (score 0):

```
let overlayHTML = `
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
`
let overlay = document.createElement("div");
    overlay.innerHTML = overlayHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(overlay);

function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}
```

I am assuming you know how to make the beginning of the userscript

```
//@match   www.thewebsite.com
```

etc